# What is the name of a property of a class?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm looking through the React documentation and I've come across this code.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Is there a specific name for what they are doing here, where they are creating an object of `propTypes` on the class?

Is this just a React thing or can this be done in any ES6 code?

Why can't we just set a variable of `propTypes` within the class itself, why does it have to come outside the class?

Answer (score 5):

That's because `propTypes` is a static<sup>1</sup> property of the class, not associated with a certain instance of the class but the class itself. React's prop type-checking looks for `propTypes` of a certain component as a static property of the component's class. It's not on the class's `prototype`, but on the class itself.

If you were to declare it inside the class, it would be an instance property:

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  get propTypes() { //Not static!
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Every `Greeting` component would then have the property `propTypes` and React won't properly type-check the props. You could use a static getter and declare it as a static property of the class though:

```
static get propTypes() {
  ...
}
```

The reason it's outside the class is based on preference. Static properties and getters can be used anywhere in ES2015 (or ES6) code.

---

In future versions of ECMAScript you can declare class properties. You can use class properties now with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and the [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin (also in the [`stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) preset):

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is syntactic sugar and works exactly the same as the static getter acting as a static property of the class.

---

<sup>1</sup> Static meaning "unchanging" because the property doesn't change based on instance, it's the same across all instances because it's not associated with just one instnace.

Comment: Similar to how we can declare static methods, is it possible to declare a static property within a class, either now or in a future implementation of ECMAScript?

Comment: *"(ECMAScript 2016+ or ES7+)"* since this feature is neither part of ES2016 and ES2017 we should just refrain from mentioning any spec version for experimental features. I think it's more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) is a React specific API. It's a way that o tell React to perform basic runtime type-checking of the properties you pass to a component. In your example, you are saying that `Greeting` components can take a `name` property of type string, but it's not required.

The way that this special `propTypes` property is defined is not specific to React, though, it's just an ES6 static class property. It's a property associated with the class declaration itself (`Greeting.propTypes`), *not* instances of the class (`new Greeting().propTypes` is `undefined`). There's actually a [newer ES7+ syntax](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers) you can use which is equivalent:

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
  };
  render() { }
}
console.log(Greeting.propTypes) // { name: ... }
```

Comment: I thought this was the case with ES7, but when I try to do this I get an error in my console stating the equals sign is an unexpected token, even though my preset is set to latest. Do I need different preset than latest to compile ES7? EDIT: Just seen the above that I need transform-class-properties plugin.

Comment: Are you using Babel with [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin?

Comment: @THughes Yeah I guess it's not actually part of the ES7 spec, it's a spec beyond that. (I personally use TypeScript which has had it built-in for awhile.)

Comment: Yes, it's an experimental feature. It's not part of any spec yet. Mentioning ES7+ will just confuse people IMO.

Answer (score -1):

You declare / define a class and you instantiate objects of  a certain class.